# Running rpy2 in parallel using multiprocessing raises weird exception that cannot be caught

Tags: python, r, multithreading, parallel-processing, rpy2

So this is a problem that I have not been able to solve, and neither do I know of a good way to make a MCVE out of. Essentially, it has been briefly discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175930/3765319), but as the comments show, there was some disagreement, and the final verdict is still out. Hence I am posting a similar question again, hoping to get a better answer.

### Background

I have sensor data from a couple of thousand sensors, that I get every minute. My interest lies in forecasting the data. For this I am using the ARIMA family of forecasting models. Long story short, after discussion with the rest of my research group, we decided to use the `Arima` function available in the R package `forecast`, instead of the `statsmodels` implementation of the same.

### Problem Definition

Since, I have data from a few thousand sensors, for which I would like to at least analyse a whole week's worth of data (to begin with), and since a week has 7 days, I have 7 times the number of sensors data with me. Essentially a some 14k sensor-day combinations. Finding the best ARIMA order (which minimizes BIC) and forecasting the next day of week data takes about 1 minute for each sensor-day combination. Which means upwards of 11 days to just process one week data on a single core!

This is obviously a waste, when I have 15 more cores just idling away the whole time. So, obviously, this is a problem for parallel processing. Note that each sensor-day combination does not influence any other sensor-day combination. Also, the rest of my code is fairly well profiled, and optimized.

### Issue

The issue is that I get this weird error that I cannot catch anywhere. Here is the error reproduced:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 429, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/home/kartik/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/robject.py", line 55, in _reduce_robjectmixin
    rinterface_level=rinterface_factory(rdumps, rtypeof)
ValueError: Mismatch between the serialized object and the expected R type (expected 6 but got 24)
```

Here are a few characteristics of this error that I have discovered:

1. It is raised in the `rpy2` package
2. It has something to do with Thread 3. Since Python is zero indexed, I am guessing this is the fourth thread. Therefore, 4x6 = 24, which adds up to the numbers shown in the final error statement
3. `rpy2` is being used in only one place in my code where it might have to recode returned values into Python types. Protecting that line in `try: ... except: ...` does not catch that exception
4. The exception is not raised when I ditch the multiprocessing and call the function within a loop
5. The exception does not crash the program, just suspends it forever (till I Ctrl+C it into terminating)
6. All that I tried till now, have had no effect in resolving the error

### Things Tried

I have tried everything from extreme procedural coding, with functions to deal with the least cases (that is only one function to be called in parallel), to extreme encapsulation, where the executable block in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` calls a function which reads in the data, does the necessary grouping, then passes the groups to another function, which imports `multiprocessing` and calls another function in parallel, which imports the processing module that imports `rpy2`, and passes the data to the `Arima` function in R.

Basically, it doesn't matter if `rpy2` is called and initialized deep inside function nests, such that it has no idea another instance might be initialized, or if it is called and initialized once, globally, the error is raised if `multiprocessing` is involved.

### Pseudo Code

Here is an attempt to present at least some basic pseudo code such that the error might be reproduced.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def arima_select(y, order):
    from rpy2 import robjects as ro
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
    pandas2ri.activate()
    forecast = importr('forecast')

    res = forecast.Arima(y, order=ro.FloatVector(order))
    return res

def arima_wrapper(data):
    data = data[['tstamp', 'val']]
    data.set_index('tstamp', inplace=True)
    return arima_select(data, (1,1,1))

def applyParallel(groups, func):
    from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for _, group in groups])
    return pd.concat(ret_list, keys=[name for name, _ in groups])

def wrapper():
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=[1], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['day'] = df['tstamp'].dt.day
    res = applyParallel(df.groupby(['sensor', 'day']), arima_wrapper)
    print(res)
```

Obviously, the above code can be encapsulated further, but I think it should reproduce the error quite accurately.

### Data Sample

Here is the output of `print(data.head(6))` when placed immediately below `data.set_index('tstamp', inplace=True)` in `arima_wrapper` from the pseudo code above:

[image]

Or alternatively, data for a sensor, for a whole week can be generated simply with:

```
def data_gen(start_day):
    r = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2016-09-{}'.format(str(start_day)),
                                periods=24*60, freq='T'),
                  name='tstamp')
    d = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, 80, 1440), name='val')
    s = pd.Series(['sensor1']*1440, name='sensor')
    return pd.concat([s, r, d], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([data_gen(day) for day in range(1,8)], ignore_index=True)
```

### Observations and Questions

The first observation is that this error is only raised when `multiprocessing` is involved, not when the function (`arima_wrapper`) is called in a loop. Therefore, it must be associated somehow with multiprocessing issues. R is not very multiprocess friendly, but when written in the way shown in the pseudo code, each instance of R should not know about the existence of the other instances.

The way the pseudo code is structured, there must be an initialization of `rpy2` for each call inside the multiple subprocesses spawned by `multiprocessing`. If that were true, each instance of `rpy2` should have spawned its own instance of R, which should just execute one function, and terminate. That would not raise any errors, because it would be similar to the single threaded operation. Is my understanding here accurate, or am I completely or partially missing the point?

Were all instances of `rpy2` to somehow share an instance of R, then I might reasonably expect the error. What is true: is R shared among all instances of `rpy2`, or is there an instance of R for each instance of `rpy2`?

How might this issue be overcome?

Since SO hates question threads with multiple questions in them, I will prioritize my questions such that partial answers will be accepted. Here is my priority list:

1. How might this issue be overcome? A working code example that does not raise the issue will be accepted as answer even if it does not answer any other question, provided no other answer does better, or was posted earlier.
2. Is my understanding of Python imports accurate, or am I missing the point about multiple instances of R? If I am wrong, how should I edit the import statements such that a new instance is created within each subprocess? Answers to this question are likely to point me towards a probable solution, and will be accepted, provided no answer does better, or was posted earlier
3. Is R shared among all instances of `rpy2` or is there an instance of R for each instance of `rpy2`? Answers to this question will be accepted only if they lead to a resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes to the `arima_select` function in the pesudo code presented in the question work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from rpy2 import rinterface as ri

ri.initr()

def arima_select(y, order):

    def rimport(packname):
        as_environment = ri.baseenv['as.environment']
        require = ri.baseenv['require']
        require(ri.StrSexpVector([packname]),
                quiet = ri.BoolSexpVector((True, )))
        packname = ri.StrSexpVector(['package:' + str(packname)])
        pack_env = as_environment(packname)
        return pack_env

    frcst = rimport("forecast")
    args = (('y', ri.FloatSexpVector(y)),
            ('order', ri.FloatSexpVector(order)),
            ('include.constant', ri.StrSexpVector(const)))
    return frcst['Arima'].rcall(args, ri.globalenv)
```

Keeping the rest of the pseudo code the same. Note that I have since optimized the code further, and it does not require all the functions presented in the question. Basically, the following is necessary and sufficient:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from rpy2 import rinterface as ri

ri.initr()

def arima(y, order=(1,1,1)):
    # This is the same as arima_select above, just renamed to arima
    ...

def applyParallel(groups, func):
    from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
    with Pool(cpu_count(), worker_init) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for _, group in groups])
    return pd.concat(ret_list, keys=[name for name, _ in groups])

def main():
    # Create your df in your favorite way:
    def data_gen(start_day):
        r = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2016-09-{}'.format(str(start_day)),
                                    periods=24*60, freq='T'),
                      name='tstamp')
        d = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, 80, 1440), name='val')
        s = pd.Series(['sensor1']*1440, name='sensor')
        return pd.concat([s, r, d], axis=1)
    df = pd.concat([data_gen(day) for day in range(1,8)], ignore_index=True)

    applyParallel(df.groupby(['sensor', pd.Grouper(key='tstamp', freq='D')]),
                  arima) # Note one may use partial from functools to pass order to arima
```

Note that I also do not call `arima` directly from `applyParallel` since my goal is to find the best model for the given series (for a sensor and day). I use a function `arima_wrapper` to iterate through the order combinations, and call `arima` at each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

> (...) Long story short (...)

Really ?

> 1. How might this issue be overcome? A working code example that does not
>      raise the issue will be accepted as answer even if it does not answer
>      any other question, provided no other answer does better, or was
>      posted earlier.

Answers may leave a quite bit of work on your end...

> 2. Is my understanding of Python imports accurate, or am
>      I missing the point about multiple instances of R? If I am wrong, how
>      should I edit the import statements such that a new instance is
>      created within each subprocess? Answers to this question are likely to
>      point me towards a probable solution, and will be accepted, provided
>      no answer does better, or was posted earlier

Python packages/modules are "uniquely" imported across your process which means that all code using the package/module within the process is using the same single import (you don't have a copy per `import` in a given block).

Because of this, I'd recommend to use an initialization function when creating your Pool rather than repeatedly import rpy2 and setup the conversion each time a task is sent to a worker. You may also gain in performance if each task is short.

```
def arima_select(y, order):
    # FIXME: check whether the rpy2.robjects package
    #        should be (re) imported as ro to be visible          
    res = forecast.Arima(y, order=ro.FloatVector(order))
    return res

forecast = None

def worker_init():
    from rpy2 import robjects as ro
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
    from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
    pandas2ri.activate()
    global forecast
    forecast = importr('forecast')

def applyParallel(groups, func):
    from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
    with Pool(cpu_count(), worker_init) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for _, group in groups])
    return pd.concat(ret_list, keys=[name for name, _ in groups])
```

> 3. Is R shared among all
>      instances of rpy2 or is there an instance of R for each instance of
>      rpy2? Answers to this question will be accepted only if they lead to a
>      resolution of the problem.

rpy2 is making R available by linking its C shared library. One such library *per Python process*, and that's as a stateful library (R not able to handle concurrency). I think that your issue has more to do with object serialization (see http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_serialization.html#object-serialization) than with concurrency.

What is happening is some apparent confusion when reconstructing the R objects after Python pickled the rpy2 object. More specifically, when looking that the R object types mentioned in the error message:

```
>>> from rpy2.rinterface import str_typeint
>>> str_typeint(6)
'LANGSXP'
>>> str_typeint(24)
'RAWSXP'
```

I am guessing that the R object returned by `forecast.Arima` contains an unevaluated R expression (for example the call that lead to that result object) and when serializing and unserializing it is coming back as something different (a raw vector of bytes). This is possibly a bug with R's own serialization mechanism (since rpy2 is using it behind the hood). For now, and solve your issue, you may want to extract what `forecast.Arima` what you care most about and only return that from the function call ran by the worker.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I'll try out your suggestions. My extremely long question was born out of my own uncertainty in presenting the problem. I appreciate you spending time to read through it. I broke it down into sections so that people who know this stuff can skip to the parts they find relevant. I don't mind doing a lot of work, I wanted to know the workings behind the scenes so that I could modify my code appropriately. Till now, I was blindly changing code in hopes that the error would magically vanish.

Comment: No problem. It is not a simple issue, it seems, and I somehow managed to understand it (so success on your end ;-) ).

Comment: BTW, I edited my answer with a possible specific cause for the issue.

Comment: The approach we discussed above did not work. After many tries, I was still getting the same error. I decided to use purely the low-level `rinterface` module instead of anything from the `robjects` module. The [`initr`](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/rinterface.html#initialization) initializer is called within the `arima` function from my question, as well as the [`rimport`](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/rinterface.html#r-packages-as-environments) function. Now, I get this error: `RuntimeError: R cannot evaluate code before being initialized.` Any insights?

Comment: Basically, I assumed that the `robjects` module might be initializing R on import, and since imports are globally shared, all R jobs are being handled by just one R instance. However, `initr` seems to initialize R only when called, and by calling it within each process, I hoped to have an instance of R for each process. Now it dies with this other weird error. Note that this error is also being raised by Thread-3, like the previous one. I am running on an 8 core machine, and of that the trial data spins up 5 cores.

Comment: I solved it by placing `rpy2.rinterface.initr()` in the global space. Doesn't require the init function. Just the use of `rinterface` instead of `robjects`... I'll post what works as a solution soon.

Comment: You don't need to guess the answer to some of the questions. The `robjects` module is initializing R on import, as a quick visit to the documentation may indicate it: http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/introduction.html#getting-started . The imports are globally shared **within a process** (as noted in the answer), not across sibling processes.

Comment: @Igautier, I have posted the code that works as answer below. Please take a minute to read it and comment as to why it does work. What is the difference between that and importing `robjects` instead of `rinterface` at the start of the program? Thank you for helping me understand.

Comment: @Kartik As outlined in the doc, importing `rpy2.robjects` implies an initialization of the embedded R while importing the low-level interface `rpy2.rinterface` doesn't (so as to allow one to change initialization parameters). Did you check the doc ? I may not want to read what you are writing if you are not reading what I am writing ;-). Initializing R in the parent process (`multiprocessing.Pool` creates child processes) is required when returning rpy2 objects because unpickling is currently done at the `rinterface` level (and it needs an initialized R process - may be this is in the doc...).

Comment: @Igautier, of course I am reading all that you write. I checked the docs before you pointed it out; I have pretty much combed the rpy2 docs entirely (in fact, it started showing up in my quick links in my browser's home page). I have been working on this for a good 2 weeks before solving the problem. And that's why I am confused. Running `import rpy2.robjects` at the start of the program causes the weird error, but running `import rpy2.rinterface as ri` then `ri.initr()` does not. Please see my answer for the code that worked. Perhaps the behavior is influenced by how forecast is imported...

Comment: @Kartik : Awesome! The doc needs badly people that point out where it is lacking or plainly incomprehensible (which is why I point to it). Otherwise, until you are able to provide a self-contained example showing the issue one can only guess (a bit or a lot) when trying to answer. Writing a self-contained example is not always easy. It can be hard work actually, but the more it is the more you are helping the person trying to answer. It can make the identification, acknowledgment, and subsequent fix of a bug much easier / faster.