# Converting numpy to R array using rpy2 low level interface

Tags: python, numpy, rpy2

There are a lot of related answers on SO, but all of them use the high-level `robjects` interface provided by [`rpy2`](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io). But, if I wanted to use the low-level interface, how do I go about it? Following is a MCVE (provided you have the [package `copula`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/copula/index.html) installed in R):

#### Alternative 1, using just the low-level interface as in [the docs](http://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/numpy.html#low-level-interface)

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2 import rinterface as ri

ri.initr()

def rimport(packname):
    as_environment = ri.baseenv['as.environment']
    require = ri.baseenv['require']
    require(ri.StrSexpVector([packname]),
            quiet = ri.BoolSexpVector((True, )))
    packname = ri.StrSexpVector(['package:' + str(packname)])
    pack_env = as_environment(packname)
    return pack_env

Copula = rimport('copula')

# The ri.SexpVector line causes the problem, but this is how the docs has it.
gc = Copula['gofCopula'](copula=Copula['gumbelCopula'](dim=5),
                         x=ri.SexpVector(np.random.randn(100,5), ri.REALSXP),
                         N=ri.IntSexpVector((1000,)),
                         simulation=ri.StrSexpVector(('mult',)))
```

Dies with:

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-63487c32d528> in <module>()
      2                          x=ri.SexpVector(np.random.randn(100,5), ri.REALSXP),
      3                          N=ri.IntSexpVector((1000,)),
----> 4                          simulation=ri.StrSexpVector(('mult',)))
      5 
      6 gc

RRuntimeError: Error: (d <- ncol(x)) > 1 is not TRUE
```

#### Alternative 2, using `numpy2ri`, as shown in all answers on SO

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2 import rinterface as ri
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri

ri.initr()
numpy2ri.activate()

def rimport(packname):
    as_environment = ri.baseenv['as.environment']
    require = ri.baseenv['require']
    require(ri.StrSexpVector([packname]),
            quiet = ri.BoolSexpVector((True, )))
    packname = ri.StrSexpVector(['package:' + str(packname)])
    pack_env = as_environment(packname)
    return pack_env

Copula = rimport('copula')

# Automatic conversion does not happen!
gc = Copula['gofCopula'](copula=Copula['gumbelCopula'](dim=5),
                         x=np.random.randn(100,5), # Hoping for automatic conversion
                         N=ri.IntSexpVector((1000,)),
                         simulation=ri.StrSexpVector(('mult',)))
```

Dies with:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-17b2b5105f01> in <module>()
     24                          x=np.random.randn(100,5),
     25                          N=ri.IntSexpVector((1000,)),
---> 26                          simulation=ri.StrSexpVector(('mult',)))
     27 
     28 gc

ValueError: All parameters must be of type Sexp_Type,or Python int/long, float, bool, or None
```

#### Alternative 3, using both together

Dies just like Alternative 1.

---

#### Additional Notes

**1)**

```
list(ri.SexpVector(np.random.randn(100,5), ri.REALSXP))
```

Is a list that contains `NA_real_`, exactly 100 of them.

**2)**

If I ditch the low-level interface, and just use the high-level interface, everything works fine. But that is not what I am looking for.

```
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import numpy2ri

numpy2ri.activate()

Copula = importr('copula')
gc = Copula.gofCopula(copula=partial(Copula.gumbelCopula, dim=5)(),
                      x=np.random.randn(100,5),
                      N=1000,
                      simulation='mult')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your praise of the high-level interface and the work that went into it, although an implicit one: it is indeed designed to "just work".

The low-level interface is quite close to R's C-level API and its use may require more knowledge about it that would deem reasonable to expect from a Python audience. Note that the documentation published is unfortunately not complete because the docstrings are not included ([issue with readthedocs](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/411/)).

I'd encourage you to use the high-level interface unless a specific reason not to, but since the source is open what is happening in the converter can be checked easily (it is [here](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/8d6689a1cd4c1484664b3576c706970813bee738/rpy/robjects/numpy2ri.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#numpy2ri.py-77)).

Comment: Hello again, Igautier! I hope you've been doing great. In the discussion following [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40384442/3765319) before, we found some limitations with the high-level interface and multiprocessing. I usually work with large datasets, and, unfortunately, a lot of great statistical packages have no equivalent in Python (copula being one of them). So I must use R. It takes about 14 hours to fit a copula model to one subset of my data, of which I have 28. So, parallel is the way to go. Hence, I am looking to use the low-level interface which works with multiprocessing

Comment: The real question I have is, how to convert numpy array to R matrix, while preserving the shape of the array, using the low-level `rinterface`. Although the high-level api is amazing, and I really appreciate all the great work that has gone into making it, it does not solve my specific problem. Thank you for pointing out the exact location for `numpy2ri` in the source. That was very helpful to replicate in my scripts.